Using ConfiguredGraphFactory for a graph defined in the gremlin server graph object
I've configured JanusGraph to use ConfiguredGraphFactory and its working without issue. I'm trying to define the graphs in the server config file so I can check in to git and when I deploy to test the config handles creating the new graphs. I expected that I could add the graph similar to how ConfigurationManagementGraph is added:
graphs: {
  ConfigurationManagementGraph: conf/janusgraph-cql-configurationgraph.properties,
  graph1: conf/graph1-local.properties,
}

where conf/graph1-local.properties looks like this:
gremlin.graph=org.janusgraph.core.ConfiguredGraphFactory
storage.backend=cql
graph.graphname=graph1
storage.hostname=127.0.0.1

cache.db-cache = true
cache.db-cache-clean-wait = 20
cache.db-cache-time = 180000
cache.db-cache-size = 0.5

What I'm finding is that this sort of works. The graph is created, but I can only access it through JanusGraphFactory. ConfiguredGraphFactory.getGraphNames() only has the graphs I manually added through the ConfiguredGraphFactory API.
Because of this, a graph traversal source isn't being bound so graph1_traversal does not exist which means my Java client does not work:
GraphTraversalSource(DriverRemoteConnection.using("127.0.0.1", 8182, "graph1_traversal")); 

I can make it work by creating a groovy script as described here, but I suspect because the graph configuration isn't managed by ConfigurationManagementGraph it won't be accessible by name only on all nodes in the Cassandra cluster.
I can go back to manually creating the graph, but I'm hoping there's a better solution because manually creating these graphs seems like the wrong way to do this.
